# BigInteger Java How To Recreate A Formula

Tags: java, biginteger

[image]

I tried to recreate this formula i am sure it's correct but the problem it gives me infinity and i need your help to transform it to BigInteger please help if possible

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double X = Input.nextDouble();
        double Y = Input.nextDouble();
        double Ans = 0;
        for (int I = 1; I <= 20; I++) {
            for (int J = 1; J <= 20; J++) {
                Ans += Math.log10(1 + Math.exp(Math.pow(-1, I + J) * (((Math.pow(I, 2) * X)) + (Math.pow(J, 2)) * Y)));

            }
        }

        System.out.println(Ans);
    }

}
```

Comment: what exactly you can't do?

Comment: Image
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/napHC.jpg)

Comment: When i print the number it prints for me Infinity :(

Comment: it is log to the base `e` and not 10.

Comment: if you solve for equation 1/x + 1/y = 1/14 and x,y<100 then possible combination to try would be `x:18y:63
x:21y:42
x:28y:28
x:42y:21
x:63y:18`

Comment: Why would you need `BigInteger`? how could it solve your problem?

Comment: Ok i changed it to Log to the base e and when i type x:21 y:42 it gives me infinity i will show you what i mean by infinity. @dkb [link](https://imgur.com/Xa4q4rZ) i want the left part of the question to work.

Comment: Yes, I am getting infinity at i=1 and J=18, so after that, you will get infinity.

Comment: I approximate it log(1+e^x) to log(e^x) ~ x, so if you sum it up, it leads to `Ans+=Math.pow(-1, I + J) * ((I*I * X) + (J*J) * Y);` else exact values can be checked here: https://www.google.com/search?ei=DUJ1XObrNYm7rQGwmJ7IBw&q=%281%2Be%5Ex%29%281%2Be%5E-x%29%281%2Be%5E2x%29%281%2Be%5E-2x%29%281%2Be%5E5x%29%281%2Be%5E-5x%29&oq=%281%2Be%5Ex%29%281%2Be%5E-x%29%281%2Be%5E2x%29%281%2Be%5E-2x%29%281%2Be%5E5x%29%281%2Be%5E-5x%29&gs_l=psy-ab.12...5697.22000..22996...0.0..0.179.1308.0j8......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.iZNxJaGd048